# IIS 8 as localhost development server: Long refresh times

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, dropbox, iis-8

I have IIS 8 on my workstation. I'm building ASP.NET applications and I continuously encounter extremely large reload times. I've set debug to "false" in web config files. I don't know what else to check. I'm working in visual studio. I know the reload time is longer if I 'build' my project but this is happening even when I'm changing markup. I am also using dropbox as my web root. Other developers are doing this as well and they aren't encountering this issue.

This issue is isolated to Chrome. I'm not experiencing long refresh times in Firefox or IE. Also, this only applies to localhost. Everything else in Chrome is very quick.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the application pool is timing out and has to spin back up for the next request? The default timeout is 20 minutes.

Comment: I verified the application pool timeout. It is indeed 20 minutes but the reload time is not that long. It averages about 2 to 3 minutes. I also changed the identity for the application pool from my user account to the ApplicationPoolIdentity with no change in performance.